# apt update fails / cannot install pkgs: key not working?

Tags: ros, ros2, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to install packages, I'm seeing errors similar to the following:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu <YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION>/main amd64 <SOME_ROS_PKG> amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-132757-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
```

While running `sudo apt update` I see the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org <YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION> InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116
```

and or:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/<YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION>/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

While running `sudo apt install` I see the following error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated! <some_pkgs>
```

and also sometimes (just an example, could be any package or ROS version):

```
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-realtime-tools/ros-kinetic-realtime-tools_1.11.1-0xenial-20190320-130942-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
```

This completely prevents me from installing ROS (and related) packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325039/apt-update-fails-/-cannot-install-pkgs:-key-not-working?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-08

Post score: 34

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-08**:
Related: #q324350.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### Cause

The old key has been revoked as part of the measures to deal with a recent security incident with `build.ros.org` ([Security issue on ROS build farm](https://discourse.ros.org/t/security-issue-on-ros-build-farm/9342)).

The key has been updated and the old one is no longer valid, causing the issues with `apt update` and `apt install`.

The keys have also changed for the ROS 2 repositories, see: [Key rotation for ROS 2 apt repositories](https://discourse.ros.org/t/key-rotation-for-ros-2-apt-repositories/9363).

Compare:

- old key: `421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116`
- new key: `C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654`

#### Solution

Refer to [New GPG keys deployed for packages.ros.org](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-gpg-keys-deployed-for-packages-ros-org/9454) for the full write-up, but as a summary these are the commands for Ubuntu (and Debian):

**Remove the old key**

- on Ubuntu 16.04 and newer (with ROS Kinetic, Melodic, etc):

  ```
   sudo apt-key del 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
  ```
- on Ubuntu 15.10 and older (ie: 14.04, from [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-gpg-keys-deployed-for-packages-ros-org/9454/5)):

  ```
   sudo apt-key del B01FA116
  ```

**Import the new key**

This command should work on all versions of Ubuntu:

```
# add the new key
sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

if this results in errors (similar to "gpg: keyserver receive failed: End of file" or others indicating the key server could not be reached), an alternative would be (make sure `curl` is installed):

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Final step**

At this point make sure to run `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update`. You should receive no errors and subsequent `sudo apt install` commands should also now work.

#### Additional notes

Installation tutorials are in the process of being updated, so if you're following one and you are seeing key-related errors, check that the tutorial is using the correct key.

If it isn't, notify the author or maintainer of the tutorial or website so it can be updated.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 114

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2019-06-10**:
this helped me. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [Zacryon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40560/zacryon/) on 2019-06-11**:
Thank you!
A little addition: Add the "-E" option to sudo in order to use environment variables in case you are trying to connect from beyond a firewall. (This requires to set the proxy variables for apt e.g. in "/etc/apt/conf.d".)

```
sudo -E  apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/654973

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
@Zacryon: I feel it's rather specific to your setup, but I've updated the answer.

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2019-06-19**:
This worked for me as well, thanks a lot.

**Comment by [cesarhcq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40890/cesarhcq/) on 2019-06-20**:
Its work for Melodic as well

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) on 2019-06-24**:
Thanks! works :D (Ubuntu 18.04, melodic)

**Comment by [matteolucchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44226/matteolucchi/) on 2019-07-24**:
I tried this and it solved the issue with the key, but I still get:

Get:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [3.150 kB]
Err:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Writing more data than expected (3151533 > 3149706) [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

anyone else experiencing this?

**Comment by [cesarhcq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40890/cesarhcq/) on 2019-07-24**:
Did you try to execute "sudo apt-get update" again? After modification of the key.

**Comment by [matteolucchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44226/matteolucchi/) on 2019-07-24**:
Yes I get this when executing "sudo apt-get update" . The same thing happens on 2 different pcs

**Comment by [matteolucchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44226/matteolucchi/) on 2019-07-26**:
what solved my problem was to run `sudo apt-get clean` before running `sudo apt-update`

**Comment by [ani](https://answers.ros.org/users/26307/ani/) on 2019-11-27**:
That worked like a charm. Thank you.

**Comment by [Gaborka](https://answers.ros.org/users/52683/gaborka/) on 2020-07-17**:
God bless you, man! This worked on kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That didn't work for me.

This command did:

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

---

Originally posted by [nickzherdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/43078/nickzherdev/) with karma: 21 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-19**:
Can you clarify what "didn't work for me" means exactly?

It didn't import the correct key? It couldn't reach the key server? Something else?

**Comment by [nunuwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/42390/nunuwin/) on 2019-06-22**:
Thanks, this answer is work for me.

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-07-10**:
Thanks. it worked

**Comment by [mecb1407](https://answers.ros.org/users/46375/mecb1407/) on 2019-09-28**:
Thank you, it was very helpful. Regards

**Comment by [suryak614](https://answers.ros.org/users/103937/suryak614/) on 2022-05-03**:
Hi, Thank you it helped for me.

**Comment by [pans](https://answers.ros.org/users/126280/pans/) on 2022-12-07**:
I'm getting launchpad-getkeys:command not found